# When to identify loot, when not to bother?

Tags: nethack

*This is a duplicate of [When should I be taking the time to identify items, and which items should I not bother with?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221749/lots-of-loot-and-when-to-bother-with-identification) , as it was decided that question was a duplicate of [How to identify items without getting killed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-identify-items-without-getting-killed). I was too slow in editing to clearly define the question, and I'd like to ask again. To be clear: this question asks WHEN to identify, not how.*

---

There are plenty of guides on how to identify items, but I can't find any on **when** to bother with it. Certain levels may have many of the same type of monster which will drop much of the same types of items (ex, mines). Turn management can be critical in many places, say, bad circumstances, early game, little food, low-apport pets, weight considerations, etc.

Obviously, this can be highly circumstantial - say needing a particular drop - but I'm more interested in the best general approach to the best general bell-curve of turns/circumstances vs items. I'm also interested in addressing the item hoarder's fear: *"I didn't try on every [common monster]'s drops - what if I missed something good?"* When should I be taking the time to identify items, and which items should I not bother with?

---

I started a list to help answer, please do add or edit:

- all amulets *(because they are rare, and if uncursed, very desirable)*
- any items that might be a prize for a certain area *(ex, sokoban ; consult wikis)*

Comment: You should be editing your previous question, not asking it again.

Comment: @Frank Fine, we'll do it your way - maybe things have changed in three years. But if my old question doesn't get re-opened because Stack Exchange Mechanics, you get to be the subject of my disappointment eyebrows.

Comment: It's up to you to explain *how* the question is different than the duplicate.  It doesn't automatically get a pass because you say it does.  I'd recommend focusing on the differences between your question and the one it's currently duped to.  As is, I'd lean towards it being too broad, as well as a dupe.